# orgonize an unpickled file python

Tags: python, excel, pickle

I need your help, I am a beginner in python.
I unpickled a file, and I had this result, I try to organize the output, but I have failed and I ask if I can export that in Excel.

Code :

```py
import pickle
 
pickle_off = open('database/user_dict.pickle',"rb")

Personnels = pickle.load(pickle_off)

print('Personnels: ')
print(Personnels)
```

the result :

[image]

Comment: Please read [mcve] for asking a good format question.

Comment: Those are NumPy arrays. You can use Pandas to read the file and export to Excel.

Comment: MattDMo , thank you